# Restrict load data to pie chart extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have store with model and pie chart, this data also are shown in some grid. My chart show graph for one column, I want to show in chart just data, which more some value. Put minimum in axes didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

To only display data greater than some value, you will need to filter the store that the chart is displaying. Check out the docs for stores, scroll down to the "Filtering and Sorting" section.
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store